# Tensorflow error : DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I tried to install tensorflow cpu using pip in my windows8.1 64bit python3.6.0
using `pip install tensorflow`
but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Users\Laitooo
San\Desktop\tf.py", line 1, in <module>
     import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Users\Laitooo San\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py",
 line 24, in <module>
     from tensorflow.python import *   File "C:\Users\Laitooo San\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py",
 line 52, in <module>
     from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *   File "C:\Users\Laitooo
 San\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py",
 line 6, in <module>
     from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor   File "C:\Users\Laitooo
 San\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py",
 line 47, in <module>
     from google.protobuf.pyext import _message ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I downloaded python36.dll and made sure all other .dll is there and install Microsoft visual c++ 2015

I also uninstalled tensorflow and installed another version several times but without any result.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I had this error as well, and was able to resolve it by downgrading protobuf from 3.6.1 to 3.6.0:

```
pip install protobuf==3.6.0
```

Comment: Solved also for me after searching for hours in google. Great!

Comment: I think tensorflow team had upgraded protobuf requirement, this time when i installed 3.6.0 version it said "Tensorflow need protobuf 3.6.1". This might not work now.

Comment: tensorflow 2.0 require  protobuf 3.6.1

Comment: Solved my problem. I got an "tensorflow 2.0.0 has requirement protobuf>=3.6.1..." error message, but it worked anyway

Answer (score 13):

- windows 10

  - python 3.6
  - Cuda 9.0
  - cudnn-9.0-windows10-x64-v7.6.3.30
  - tensorflow-gpu == 1.12.0
  - keras == 2.2.4

problem was:

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be
>   found.

**solved with:**

```
pip install protobuf==3.6.0
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a similar issue on Github:

[Tensorflow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17386)

Problem should be resolved if you install the wheel file provided in one of the answers. You can find the wheel file here.

[Wheel file](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel/tree/master/1.6.0/py36/CPU/sse2)

You can install the wheel file with pip. First change the current directory to install location. Then,

```
pip install tensorflow-1.6.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: it uninstalled the last version of tensorflow and upgraded to 1.6 but now it give me new error "cant import name DEBUG" @Koray

Comment: Can you try the wheel files on here? If it works I will update the answer.  [wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#tensorflow)  @KilluaSan. Can you share the code you are trying to run too?

Comment: sorry by updated i meant installed the wheel using the code you provided

Comment: So I believe tensorflow is working now and you are having another problem with imports. @KilluaSan

Answer (score 2):

All official tensorflow binaries since 1.6 were made with AVX, rendering older CPUs unsupported.
In order to install recent tensorflow versions on an older CPU you can simply install tensorflow from a non-avx built wheel ( you can find some [here](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel))

```
 pip install <path to the downloaded .whl file>
```

Answer (score 0):

its the problem with python=3.6.0

Upgrade to any higher versions of python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Updating from python 3.6.0 to python 3.6.4 fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I got this (unhelpful) error after installing on python 3.7. Turns out I had not installed [cuDNN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn), the neural network package. After that, it runs without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
I made it work by uninstalling scipy and then reinstalling.
First uninstall seaborn.
`pip uninstall seaborn`
then uninstall scipy. 
`pip uninstall scipy`.
After that install both scipy and seaborn.
`pip install scipy`,
`pip install seaborn`

I hope it helps