# Import tensorflow error: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
import tensorflow
```

When i try to import tensorflow and run the code I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Ivan/PycharmProjects/AI_Numers/script.py", line 1, in <module>
import tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\PycharmProjects\AI_Numers\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\PycharmProjects\AI_Numers\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\PycharmProjects\AI_Numers\venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\Ivan\PycharmProjects\AI_Numers\venv\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.`
```

I am currently using: 
Python: 3.6.0
Tensorflow: 1.12

I've already looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092810/tensorflow-error-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found) thread, but I could not fix my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems some backward compatibility issues on the library called protobuf. You can use [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21719). But I would recommend a fresh install of python 3.6.6 with anaconda or miniconda and use conda to install tensorflow.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22794) or [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22512) could help you. Many people had problems caused by `DLL load failed`. Also [tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors) is providing a list with possible errors

Answer (score 1):

Facing the same issue on my machine after some trials found a solution which worked for me.
Steps to solve the issue:

1. Re-Install Cuda(**Till Date Tensorflow only supports Cuda V9.0** so install Cuda9.0 only)
2. Add Cuda library, bin paths to system variables
3. Add **Cudnn(Any Version is Ohkey) library** to Cuda9.0
4. Restart PC
5. Install "pip install **tensorflow-gpu==1.8**"(I tried with higher version also but not supported in my case but 1.8 easily got installed)