# Python Spyder IDE Errors - Tensorflow Machine Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, artificial-intelligence, spyder

I'm trying to get setup to be able to start writing code for a Machine Learning / Chatbot project I was assigned to at work. After following all of the tensorflow steps online, I'm getting errors.

Errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\chatbot.py\package.company.chatbot\main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Software\Eng_APPS\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found
```

.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(raw_input=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

Comment: It looks similar to this thread [DLL Load Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092810/tensorflow-error-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found/53111377#53111377).