# Make train-core // Import Error : DDL Load failed

Tags: python, rasa-core

I wanted to get the starter-pack-rasa-stack https://github.com/RasaHQ/starter-pack-rasa-stack working for me.
While trying to make train-core I encountered a Problem with DDL load.

I want to say that I am using the german Version of spacy_sklearn, if this makes any difference.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\train.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rasa_core import config, cli
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\config.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rasa_core.policies import PolicyEnsemble
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\policies\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from rasa_core.policies.keras_policy import KerasPolicy
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\policies\keras_policy.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 59, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\Yannic\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: Die angegebene Prozedur wurde nicht gefunden.
```

This is my Output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pip install protobuf==3.6.0
```

This solved my Problem.

[Tensorflow error : DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092810/tensorflow-error-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found?rq=1)