# Unable to train RASA-CORE Model throwing traceback :from google.protobuf.pyext import _message ImportError: DLL load failed: Access is denied

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, makefile, rasa-nlu, rasa-core

windows 10
Python 3.7.3
I am trying to train my rasa-core model using make commend and it's throwing below traceback in windows commandprompt:

I have tried running CMD as administrator and then training rasa-core model but it gives me same traceback. Can't find anything related to rasacore in internet so not sure if other solutions are relevant to this error

```
C:\Users\mrawat\starter-pack-rasa-stack>make train-core
python -m rasa_core.train -d domain.yml -s data/stories.md -o models/current/dialogue -c policies.yml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 183, in _run_module_as_main
    mod_name, mod_spec, code = _get_module_details(mod_name, _Error)
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 109, in _get_module_details
    __import__(pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from rasa_core.test import test
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    from rasa_core.policies.form_policy import FormPolicy
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\policies\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from rasa_core.policies.policy import Policy
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rasa_core\policies\policy.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from tensorflow.core.framework.graph_pb2 import *
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\graph_pb2.py", line 6, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\mrawat\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: Access is denied.
make: *** [train-core] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe protobuf 3.7.1 is not compatible with rasa-core starter pack model downgrading the protobuf==3.6.0 solved my problem in windows10 machine.

pip install protobuf==3.6.0

found details :[Make train-core // Import Error : DDL Load failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55589113/make-train-core-import-error-ddl-load-failed)