# Python → ImportError: DLL load failed: the specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot

I'm trying to run a chatbot wrote in python, but everytime I run the code these errors appear:

```
  File "c:/Users/lenovo/Desktop/Codi/Codi.py", line 7, in <module>
    import tflearn
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\CodiVENV\lib\site-packages\tflearn\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from . import config
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\CodiVENV\lib\site-packages\tflearn\config.py", line 3, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\CodiVENV\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\CodiVENV\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\CodiVENV\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "c:\users\lenovo\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\CodiVENV\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\Envs\CodiVENV\lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: the specified procedure could not be found
```

At the beginningI thought it was an error of the bad configuration of PyCharm, but I tried also in Visual Studio Code with different interpreters and the problem still exists.
I already tried to upgrade tensorflow package, but nothing change.
What can I do?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092810/tensorflow-error-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found/53111377#53111377

Comment: Unfortunately not