# Tensorflow library ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have installed Python 3.7 and tensorflow but when i "import tensorflow as tf" , i have the follow error

"Tensorflow library ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found"

here is my code

`import tensorflow as tf`

Comment: DLL mean a problem in C++.  do you have visual studio instaled?. Can you show the instalation process that you are using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow error : DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092810/tensorflow-error-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found)

Comment: Have you tried downgrading tenserflow? 

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0

```

Comment: Try searching for similar questions. Only after that post your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you are hoping for but what worked for me was just to downgrade the version of tensorflow to 2.0

```
pip install tensorflow==2.0
```