# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found., tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to import tensorflow as tf, the following error is come up

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.

The code is:

import tensorflow as tf

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tensorflow error : DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52092810/tensorflow-error-dll-load-failed-the-specified-procedure-could-not-be-found)

Comment: thanks so much that was so helpful. The issue was solved by running: pip install protobuf==3.6.0

Answer (score 0):

From comments

> Issue was solved by installing `protobuf` as `pip install protobuf==3.6.0` (paraphrased from Proko and Mohammed AL-SAADI)